# Exporting artwork at specific size in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have the following artwork in the latest version of Illustrator CC:

[image: artwork in illustrator]

Ignore the black rectangle, I only added that so that you and I can actually see the artwork (not sure if there is a better way).

**Question:**

How can I export this artwork with the following criteria:

1. Height: 40px
2. Padding top and bottom: 12px
3. Padding left and right: 0px

As PNG format.

Is this doable? I cannot find any of these things in the export window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's doable.

- Create a new document (or an artboard) the size you want in pixels.
- Switch on the rulers, and add guides for the padding.
- Enable the pixel preview
- Paste your artwork, resize/position as necessary.

[image]

- Edit the artboard size so that there is no gap left or right.
- *File > Export > Export for Screens* (or you can use *Save for Web* and use the "clip to artboard" option)

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: I see, so from the start, I have to set out everything the way I want it ending up. I couldn't get what I want right at the export step?

Comment: @Ciwan Well, since there are no options to add these specifications at the export stage, using the artboard, and positioning/scaling it, and using guides are the options I would choose to get the job done.

Comment: @Ciwan BTW, you don't have to create a new document, you can add additional artboards in your main document to use for this purpose.

Comment: I suspect you want to use that PNG for web design purpose. In this case, I would advise to export your PNG at the right image size and then use CSS to add padding (or margin)

Comment: @Vinny yes, adding padding in CSS would be better for websites.